# How to populate a column depending on the value of the another column in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am struggling with this excel problem. I have an Excel with over 4000 rows. I am wondering how I can populate columns, for example, the left column with colors depending on the fruits from the right column. Is there a way that I could automatically edit the same values? Thank you

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: It sounds like you want a "lookup function", e.g. [VLookup()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a lookup table of fruits and colors. For example, you might place the fruits in D2:D4 and colors in E2:E4. Then in your column A, use XMATCH:

```
=XLOOKUP(B1,$D$2:$D$4,$E$2:$E$4)
```

[image]

VLOOKUP will also work as will INDEX( MATCH.  If you have XLOOKUP it is easy and safer than VLOOKUP.

VLOOKUP version:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,$D$2:$E$4,2)
```

INDEX MATCH version:

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$4, MATCH(B2,$D$2:$D$4,0) )
```

If you want to be able to edit the contents of fruits and colors, it would be easier to put them into an Excel Table (CTRL-t). Then your formula would be:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Color], MATCH(B2,Table1[Fruit],0) )
```

which would automatically expand and contract as you add/delete fruits.

You can also hard code the values of the table, but that is not a good idea because you would have to hard code it into each formula when you want to make changes. Here is hard coding:

```
=INDEX({"red","yellow","orange"}, MATCH(B3,{"apple","banana","orange"},0) )
```

Comment: The only way that can happen is if the fruit/color table is not correct or there is a typo in the formula. Try INDEX MATCH - VLOOKUP is not a good function in any case. If your table column structure ever changes, VLOOKUP will silently give errors. The worst errors are silent errors.

Comment: A small remark: `=VLOOKUP(B1,$D$2:$E$4,2)` does not look for an exact match by default like `XLOOKUP()` would. I'd use the 4th parameter to ensure it will.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, truly the way you explains it just revises me small things on Excel which i usually forget. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula. No need extra table.

```
=XLOOKUP(B1,{"apple","banana","orange"},{"red","yellow","orange"})
```

[image]

Comment: It returns #NAME?

Comment: So the OP would edit the formula in each location every time he has a change to the values which is so much better than having an extra table.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick For small amount of values this is best. But for many many values extra table would be good choice.

Comment: So when he needs to edit the table, he just changes it in the 4000 locations where he has pasted the formula. Yep - much better than having a table that he can edit and I can see why this is a new answer rather than a comment.